# What's the difference the two regular expression characters \b and \<

Tags: regex, bash

In the script I'm reading about regular expressions it says:

- `'\b'` hits the front border of the word
- `'\<'` hits the start of the word

So what's the difference in using the following

- `\b` over `\<`
- `\b` over `\>`

Comment: @shime: why did you tag this [perl]? It doesn't mention perl at all.

Comment: @Wooble regexes are massively used in perl so I thought perlers could help.

Comment: @shime, but his question is not about Perl regular expressions. `\<` simply matches `<` in Perl. Removing "perl" tag.

Answer (score 4):

My `man grep` tells me about `\b`:

> The  symbols  `\<`  and  `\>`  respectively  match  the empty string at the beginning and end of a word.  The symbol `\b` matches the empty string at the  edge  of a word, [...]

So `\bfoo\b` would match wherever `\<foo\>` would match.

On the other hand: There are so many regexp variants, that it is hard to tell what yours is doing with `\b`.

Answer (score 4):

`\b` is like `\<` and `\>` combined:

- `\<` match at beginning of word,
- `\>` match at end of word,
- `\b` match at the begining OR end of word,
- `\B` matches except at the beginning or end of a word.

Comment: if I put `\b` at the begining of the word it will only match the begining of the word and if I put it at the end of the word it will only match the end of the word. With just one `\b` you can't match the begining and the end

Comment: I don't understand - `\bfoo\b` has basically same effect as `\<foo\>`, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Your source appears to be wrong, or at least incomplete. `\b` matches *any* border, not just the front one. Quote `man grep`:

> The symbols `\<` and `\>` respectively match the empty string at the beginning and end of a word. The symbol `\b` matches the empty string at the edge of a word

---

- `grep`'s `\b` is equivalent to `grep`'s `\(\<\|\>\)`

In case you are familiar with Perl regular expressions,

- `grep`'s `\<` is equivalent to Perl's `(?<!\w)(?=\w)`
- `grep`'s `\>` is equivalent to Perl's `(?<=\w)(?!\w)`
- `grep`'s `\b` is equivalent to Perl's `\b`
- `grep`'s `\b` is equivalent to Perl's `(?:(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w))`

Comment: Note: `grep`'s definition of "word" is probably different than Perl's aka Unicode's.